# Layout with sticky tabs and view pager

Tags: android

I want to create a layout like this. where there are more information on header of the layout (i.e Image, title, few text views, buttons). and there is a tab below the header layout and a view pager which contains each tab data.
When I scroll up the tabs need to stick on the top.
Please help me here. Thank a lot in advanced.

[image]

I have tried the below code but got problem when the header layout content is too large then all content is not visible and tabs goes below the screen size and does not appear again when scroll up.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_view">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carouselLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/group_profile_image_height">
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/album_view_background"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/comment_post_button_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                        android:shadowDx="1"
                        android:shadowDy="1"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:id="@+id/content_title"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/left_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:tint="@color/white"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_left"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
                        android:tint="@color/white"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/image_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/right_arrow"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/left_right_arrow_margin" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/carouselLayout"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/owner_detail_layout"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/view_default_padding"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_default_padding"
                        android:background="@color/grey_light"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <classes.common.ui.BezelImageView
                            android:id="@+id/owner_image"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_height"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_width"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:foregroundGravity="right"
                            app:maskDrawable="@drawable/circle_mask"
                            app:borderDrawable="@drawable/circle_border" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                            android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:id="@+id/owner_name"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <classes.common.ui.SelectableTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                        android:textColor="@color/body_text_1"
                        android:id="@+id/listing_description"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:id="@+id/likeCommentContent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:background="@color/grey_light"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:id="@+id/likeBlock"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:id="@+id/likeIcon" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:id="@+id/likeCountView" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/light_gray" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:id="@+id/commentBlock"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:id="@+id/commentIcon" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/commentCountView"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                        android:id="@+id/review_wishlist_layout"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:id="@+id/review_block"
                            android:background="@color/grey_light"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:id="@+id/review_icon" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                                android:text="@string/write_review_text"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:id="@+id/review_text" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:id="@+id/wishlist_block"
                            android:background="@color/grey_light"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:id="@+id/wishlist_icon" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/wishlist_text"
                                android:text="@string/add_wishlist_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_plus"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_short"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:id="@+id/bottomView"
                android:layout_below="@id/collapsing_toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTitleTextAppearance"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: What you have Tried  Firstly ?

Comment: Please check the above code.

Comment: Can anyone help me here ?